# How to solve queued processes in IIS

Tags: php, iis, iis-7.5, fastcgi

I'm using IIS 7.5 with PHP and I'm having troubles with my application, it is VERY slow and it can take more than 2 minutes to display the login screen.

I believe this is due to some kind of queue of requests to process.

I've taken a look at the "Worker Processes" menu in IIS and I found out there are tends request in the *DefaultAppPool* which seem to be waiting for a response.

Is this normal? How can I get rid of them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some "bottleneck" in your code, because all servers like Nginx, Apache, IIS must work well in a lot of situations (we don't talking about highload sites, because it is separated topic).

So I suggest you to try profile your code. For example you can use xhprof:

https://github.com/phacility/xhprof

And `xhprof` will show you where is "bottleneck" in your code